# Identify devices on a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express server that serves up a react app and also has a bunch of api endpoints. Clients will be connecting to the server both through a browser and through a C# application concurrently. Is there any way to identify devices in order to pair a connection made from the browser with a connection made from the C# app when they are both made from the same device?

Comment: I suppose you can see that the source IP address is the same if two separate connections are coming from the same device (though that might lead to false positives if the client is behind NAT).  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: The web app is going to include the interface for starting the C# application on the client machine, and I need to be able to tell which of the C# apps connected to the server is running on the same machine as the web app in order to send the start request. I'd like to be able to completely avoid false positives as I don't want to be starting the C# app on the wrong machine.

Comment: Well, this sounds like you need some sort of ID included with a sign-on or connection that identifies a client.  That's not hard to do with the C# app, but not so easy to get that same ID into the web app.  One idea would be to have the C# app, after it starts up, but before it connects, open a browser window and give it an URL to go to that points to your server and includes a query string that has a unique ID.  Your server can then put that ID into a cookie for that browser.  Then, the C# app identifies itself as that same ID and the browser has that ID in a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! That's similar to what we've been considering except we were thinking we'd just have to have the user manually enter the ID generated by the C# app which we were hoping to avoid. Using a cookie in the browser is an intriguing solution, I'll look more into it. Still very open to any other advice too (: